# Проблема соединения с MSSQL сервером из Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!
У меня нет опыта работы с MSSQL но из-за проблемы хостинга вынужден отказаться от Firebird и и перейти на MSSQL.
DataSnap Программа на Delphi удалённо соединяется с сервером MSSQL 2005. Через SSMS свободно соединяется а через Delphi (компонент FDConnection)-никак.

у меня установлен MSSQL 2005 и соответственно sqlncli.dll находится в папке System32, но потом установил SSMS 2012 и он в папке System32 добавил sqlncli11.dll. Не знаю сейчас что сделать- удалить только sqlncli11.dll или польностью деинсталлировать MSSQL? А как потом работать без MSSQL?
кроме этого, мой порт 1433, а порт сервера 1450. Может здесь причина?

в FireDac Connection Editor eсли в SERVER пишу:

**185.163.xxx.xx\SQLEXPRESS,1450 или 185.163.xxx.xx,1450**  выводит:

> [Firedac][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL SERVER **Native client 11.0**][SQL
>   Server] Invalid Object Name 'SyS DATABASES'

а eсли пишу **185.163.xxx.xx\SQLEXPRESS** выводит:

> Expired TimeOut

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня:

OS Windows 10, 64разрядная.

Delphi 10.2

MSSQL Server 2005 express edition RTM 9.0.1399.06

А на сервере: MSSQL Server 2005 express edition SP2

И ещё- в Grants галочки не установлены. Почему тогда сервер мне(GephaPartners) дал возможность создать таблицы? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему порт в конце? Разве не `185.163.xxx.xx,1450\SQLEXPRESS`? Кстати на скриншотах IP зарисован, а в тексте вопроса нет :)

Comment: Кстати права у Вас `db_owner`

Comment: `Invalid Object Name 'SyS DATABASES'` возникает из за того что нет каких то прав

Comment: @androschuk пробовал и так(185.163.xxx.xx,1450\SQLEXPRESS). не получается.  
На счёт прав у меня сам есть вопрос. Кто создал для меня базу не сервер говорит что у меня есть все права- и создать таблицы и удалять и изменять. Я и создаю таблицы без проблем. Хотя как видите на скрине галочки Grans  не поставлены. Как тогда сервер даёт мне возможность управлять таблицами?

Comment: Да, странно. Может FireDac запрашивает какую то доп информацию к которой нет доступа. Кстати измените пароль, потому что его засветили на первом скриншоте. Как вариант - можно попробовать подключится с помощью ADOConnection.

Comment: @androschuk, Я допустил 2 ощибки: 1) старался соединятся с бд компонентом FDConnection из клиена! 2) Переадресацию на клиенте и сервере пока не сделал. 
Сейчас новый пост опубликую. Спасибо вам.

Comment: [В истории изменений вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/755786/revisions) видно, какой был IP в ответе, его PTR заканчивается на .ge. Надеюсь, вы знаете, что делаете.

Comment: @basti 1. почему ошибка? Вы создаете приложение, которое и является клиентом. 2. Какую переадресацию?

Comment: Androchuk я в design time хотел соединяться с бд про незапушенном сервере приложения. :)